# How to select distinct values from DB separated by comma?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a front end including 2 columns, Keywords1 and keywords2 in data base they goes in a single field called keywords (separated by ,). Now I have a search screen which have a Keywords as auto complete text box, now in order populate it I need to get single values from DB, so I have something like,

```
Keywords
A
A
A,B
B,C
C,E
D,K
```

Now in order to populate them as a single listItem I need something like.

```
Keywords
A
B
C
D
k
```

So that front end doesn't contains and duplicate in it. I am not much expert in SQL, One way I know is just to get the distinct values from DB with like `%entered keywords%` and the use LINQ to separate them by comma and then get the distinct values. But that would be a lengthy path.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your database schema is faulty. You should store your keywords in a separate table, and then have a cross-reference table that ties your keywords to a specific thing.

Comment: Are the values saved comma seperated in the databse?

Comment: @HW90 Yes actually both keywords1 and keywords2 from front end merge it, separating by comma and enter into one DB field which is keywords.

Comment: @DBM I agree with you completely but this is kind of an old db design consisting many records init and convincing my old aged Manager is another challenge to make it done :)

Comment: @VishalSachdeva that is a very bad practice! have a look on the commentar of DBM!

Comment: @VishalSachdeva what kind of database do you have?

Comment: @VishalSachdeva There is nothing called sql2010

Comment: Comments about the DB schema are valid but not very useful if the DB is a legacy one and can't be changed :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit late, but an alternative answer that ends up with distinct keywords:

```
List<string> yourKeywords= new List<string>(new string[] { "A,B,C", "C","B","B,C" });

var splitted = yourKeywords
    .SelectMany(item => item.Split(','))
    .Distinct();
```

This will not work straight against the DB though. you would have to read the DB contents into memory before doing the SelectMany, since Split has not equivalent in SQL. It would then look like

```
var splitted = db.Keywords
   .AsEnumerable()
   .SelectMany(item => item.Split(','))
   .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks Mike the the first part was very helpful, Yes I create a List<string> and looped the data reader and added each item to this List and further performed operation on it.

Answer (score 1):

Getting them by using string split and Linq group by

```
        List<string> yourKeywords= new List<string>(new string[] { "A,B,C", "C","B","B,C" });
        List<string> splitted = new List<string>();
        yourKeywords.ForEach(x => splitted.AddRange(x.Split(',')));
     var t =   splitted.GroupBy(x => x);
```